# Посоветуйте книгу по С

Tags: c

За какую книжку по языку С можно браться после Керниган, Ритчи "Язык программированния Си"?

Comment: Странно, Вам уже прочитанного не хватило?

Comment: Хоче еще углубиться в язык, если возможно

Comment: Было бы интересно, если бы Вы дополнили вопрос - Какова цель столь глубокого изучения?

Comment: После освоения азов языка следует изучать технологию, которую будете использовать в реальном проекте. Например, если планируется работать с базой данных, то учите SQL, и конкретную СУБД. Если планируете написать крутую игру, то учите графику (OpenGL, DirectX) и т. п. Думаю, мысль понятна.

Comment: @0xdb , хочу получше изучить си чтобы было легче в изучении с++

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, мысль понятна)

Comment: @YaroslavK. C и С++ очень разные языки программирования. И хорошо изучив С легче в изучении С++ не станет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

МакГрат М.- Программирование на С для начинающих (Программирование для начинающих) - 2016

Я лично изучаю по этой. Она не лучше всех но для новичка самое то.

Comment: После Керниган-Ритчи советовать книжку для чайников?

Comment: Ну Вы же сами сказали, что Вас все по Си интересует.